# MNIST handwritten digit recognition with Keras

Tags: keras, mnist

My goal is to classify MNIST handwritten digits using keras. I am trying to reproduce the results from this [website](http://machinelearningmastery.com/handwritten-digit-recognition-using-convolutional-neural-networks-python-keras/).

When creating the model ("model = baseline_model()"), I get the error message
AssertionError: Keyword argument not understood: kernel_initializer

Do you know how to solve this issue ? I am using keras 1.1.1 with theano back-end

Comment: It appears that `kernel_initializer` is not an understood keyword for your version of keras. Either update or try to find the alternative in the older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's mentioned in a comment at the beginning of an article - this is a version for `keras 2.0.2`, so in order to make this example working you need to use this version of `Keras`.